# Is consuming your own API necessary in this case?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, architecture, blazor, domain-driven-design

I have a solution with:

- ASP.NET Core WebAPI project
- Blazor Server project (web)

I also have 2 Class Libraries

- Core (domain models and interfaces here)
- Infrastructure (implementation of interfaces here)

Is it worth it for my Blazor Server to consume my own WebAPI via HttpClient? Or let my Blazor Server have a DbContext in program.cs too and access the database directly?

Because calling the WebAPI with HttpClient might be slower. And if I choose to call the database directly with Blazor, then I have a lot of copy paste (DbContext, inject services, etc in Program.cs), AKA copying the whole CompositionRoot.

What's your opinion to what I should be doing as for the right approach?

Comment: Making an HTTP call to the same server does certainly seem silly, unless semantically they *should* be considered separate micro-services because there exists a liklihood of separate deployments in the future.  Alternatively, I don't see why you'd need to copy/paste anything.  Can't the two applications reference the same assemblies, class library projects, etc.?

Comment: API and Blazor both need to dependency inject services, if I chose not consume the API with HttpClient. It happens in Program.cs and I don't think having Program.cs in i.e. Infrastructure class-library is good?

Comment: This may involve creating a separate Stack Overflow question for that specific thing, but I also don't see why you need a `Program.cs` in a class library just to use dependency injection.  You may be missing something or have mis-structured something.  A class library doesn't need to inject its own dependencies.  But it can expose dependencies (usually on constructors) and the application which hosts it would supply those dependencies with *its* dependency injection setup.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, having Program.cs in a seperate project for my web apps to both reference it, is not how it's supposed to be. I have all my service implementations in my Infrastructure class library project, and both API and Blazor need to use the infrastructure services if I chose to not use HttpClient by dependency injecting the same services as in my API. But If I use HttpClient in Blazor to call my API endpoints without any dependency injection in Program.cs in Blazor - only AddHttpClient in Program.cs.

Comment: Each class library can (should) expose an extension method similar to AddHttpClient(), that would seem to address most of your concerns.

Comment: @HH Ok, that makes sense - so to be clear: Since I have class library "Infrastructure", I should have an extension method like AddHttpClient(), i.e. AddMyServices(), that dependency injects all of its (my own) services. And this approach is better than having HttpClient to call my API?

Comment: They're not so directly opposites. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to be sure to have total separation (for future microservices archtitecture) then yes, call the API with HttpClient.
But that does reduce your performance, and it's a drag.

As an alternative you can add a separate MyService.Contracts project for each MyService. That project should contain the `interface`s and also the DTOs you use for your API.

The other services should only take a dependency on each others .Contracts projects. That prevents directly calling other services.

And then each MyService project should expose a helper method to register all its services with the DI. In Program.cs you can then set everything up. Note that the actual Service classes can now be `internal` .

In the Onion Architecture view: the contracts are in an inner ring, their implementations go on the outside.